# How can I refactor this complicated transaction into my model from my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, before-filter

I have a complex save process (a cyclical reference that needs to be resolved by validating and saving and one model, validating and saving another and then updating the first with an id from the second) that has rollbacks depending on if something bad happened etc.

My models are related in this way:

- `Account`s have one `SiteContact`.
- `Account`s have many `Customer`s.
- `SiteContact`s are a type of `Customer`.
- `Customer`s belong to an `Account`

Because of the cyclical reference (i.e. `Customer`s are invalid WITHOUT an `Account` but an `Account` needs a `SiteContact` which is a type of `Customer`.) I decide to save the Account with a blank id for site contact **first**, then save the site_contact.

I have code similar to this:

```
# remove the site contact from the account because its not valid yet.
site_contact = params[:account].delete(:site_contact_attributes)
account = Account.new(params[:account])

# some pseudo code
# start database transaction
# validate account
# if valid then
#   save account
#   site_contact.account_id = account.id
#   validate site_contact
#   if valid then
#     account.site_contact_id = site_contact.id
#     save account
#     break out!
#
#   else
#     rollback transaction
#   end
# else
#   rollback transaction
# end

if Account.exists?(account)
  # everything was good! flash[:notice] and redirect somewhere
else
  # something bad happened, go back to the page and display the errors.
end
```

Is it possible to override the `Account#save` or some other method and move all of that code into my controller? I was looking at `before_save` and `before_create` but I'm worried there might be some unintended recursion since I have to save the `account` twice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller:

```
site_contact = SiteContact.new(params[:account].delete(:site_contact_attributes))
account = Account.new(params[:account])

if account.save_nested(site_contact)
 # success
else
 # error
end
```

In your `Account` model.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  def save_nested(site_contact)
    Account.transaction do
      save!
      site_contact.account_id = self.id
      site_contact.save!
      self.site_contact_id = site_contact.id
      save!
      return true
    end
    return false
  end
end
```

The `save!` will throw an exception when the validation fails. This will automatically roll back the transaction.

Comment: Its complicated. I don't do single table inheritance so there are three models/tables. Accounts depends on SiteContacts which depend on Customers which depends on Accounts. Really, this isn't anything new in relational databases, but its more complicated then having a `belongs_to` in model with a foreign key and a `has_many`/`has_one` in another model.

Comment: I didn't read the 2nd part of your question, so ignore the PS in my answer

Comment: Added additional explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

**Controller Code**

```
site_contact = params[:account].delete(:site_contact_attributes)
account = Account.new(params[:account])

if Account.validate_and_save(site_contact)
   # everything was good! flash[:notice] and redirect somewhere
else
   # something bad happened, go back to the page and display the errors.
end
```

**Model Code**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  def validate_and_save(site_contact)
   # some pseudo code
   # start database transaction
   #  validate account
   #  if valid then
   #    save account
   #    site_contact.account_id = account.id
   #    validate site_contact
   #    if valid then
   #      account.site_contact_id = site_contact.id
   #      save account
   #      break out!
   #      return true
   #    else
   #      rollback transaction
   #      return false
   #    end
   #  else
   #    rollback transaction
   #    return false
   #  end
  end
end
```